# Detect keyboard is active outside the application on android

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I am trying to detect keyboard is active or not (Outside my application) using accessibility service. For that i tried to read the notifications "choose keyboard" (When multiple key board are enabled). Following code is used.

```
public class KeyboardWatcher extends AccessibilityService {

boolean isConnected = false;
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) {
        final String packagename = String.valueOf(event.getPackageName());
        Log.d("Package", packagename);
        String msg = "";            
        List<CharSequence> s = event.getText();
        if(s.iterator().hasNext())
        {
            msg += s.iterator().next().toString();
            Log.d("MSG", msg);

        }else{
            Log.d("TYPE", event.getEventType()+"");
        }
    }else{
        Log.d("EVENT TYPE__",event.getEventType()+"");
        final String packagename = String.valueOf(event.getPackageName());
        Log.d("PNE", packagename);          
    }

}
protected void onServiceConnected() {

    if (isConnected) {
        return;
    }       
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK;
    setServiceInfo(info);
    isConnected = true;
} 
}
```

Now all notifications are logged by the application except "keyboard chooser" notification. How to read that notification, is that possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package com.sat.app.notification;
import android.content.Context;
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.util.Log;
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {
    Context context;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String title =     sbn.getNotification().extras.getString("android.title");// It will be select keyboard
        }
    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i("com.sat","Notification Removed");

   }
}
```

IN Manifest : add

```
<service android:name="com.sat.app.notification.NotificationService"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

After installing application allow reading notification in settings.
Tested and working on Android 5.0

Comment: Note, this doesn't work on 6+ anymore (at least on stock android) as the keyboard input is not a notification now, rather an icon on the bottom navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct there is no way to get that notification, the system itself detects all the available keyboards and displays them (if there is only one keyboard there will be no pop). 
As far as I know there is no way to get that notification.